Exception has occurred: DatatypeMismatch column "occurence_timestamp" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type bigint
Here are the core steps and logics of my script below:

Create and instantiate a PostgreSQLDB class object that does database operation
Use view vw_valid_case_from_db1 to get a list of case_id which will be included
df_db1_case_table is a pandas df that extracts information from the table named db1
Filter and include only cases from 2 for the rows in df_db1_case_table
I have set up a table named db2_case_table that I want to batch insert the information from the filtered df_db1_case_table (or named df_db1_case_table_filtered). The name of columns from df_db1_case_table_filtered match with the columns from db2_case_table
The problem is I am getting this error Exception has occurred: DatatypeMismatch column "occurence_timestamp" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type bigint LINE 1: ...7.0, 2259027.0, NULL, 'CA23307772', NULL, '1441', 1689711600... HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. File "some_path_to.py", line 170, in <module> cursor.executemany(insert_query, data_to_insert) psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: column "occurence_timestamp" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type bigint LINE 1: ...7.0, 2259027.0, NULL, 'CA23307772', NULL, '1441', 1689711600... HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
The section for col in timestamp_columns: of the code below is how I tried to solve this. Namely, if the data type of the (whatever)_timestamp is in 'int64' or 'float64' format, it will be enforced to be in datetime format. However, it doesn't work and the same error appears.
Additional information: if I remove all of the (whatever)_timestamp fields ['occurence_timestamp', 'reported_timestamp', 'created_timestamp', 'modified_timestamp', 'agency_extract_timestamp', 'city_extract_timestamp', 'pdf_extract_timestamp' ], the script works fine.

Script below:
import pandas as pd
import os
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from helper_db_operation import PostgreSQLDB

# Set up logging configuration
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, 
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Some database credential code
postgres_db = PostgreSQLDB(postgres_user, postgres_password, postgres_host, postgres_db_name)

# Query to fetch valid case IDs from db1 view
sql_query_get_valid_case_case_from_db1 = """
    SELECT case_id
    FROM vw_valid_case_from_db1
"""

# Execute query and load results into a Pandas DataFrame
try:
    df_db1_valid_cases = pd.read_sql(sql_query_get_valid_case_case_from_db1, postgres_db.conn)
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"Error while fetching data from db1 view: {e}")
    raise

# 1.2) connect db1_case, then apply the filter from 1.1) to exclude invalid case
# Query to fetch all case from db1 table
sql_query_get_case_table_from_db1 = """
    SELECT *
    FROM public.db1_case
"""

# Execute query and load results into a Pandas DataFrame
df_db1_case_table = pd.read_sql(sql_query_get_case_table_from_db1, postgres_db.conn)

# Apply the filter to include only those case that are in the valid list from df_db1_valid_cases
valid_case_ids = df_db1_valid_cases['case_id'].tolist()

# Filter df_db1_case_table to include only rows where the ID is in the valid case IDs
df_db1_case_table_filtered = df_db1_case_table[df_db1_case_table['id'].isin(valid_case_ids)]

# Check the result of the filtering
logging.debug(f"Filtered {len(df_db1_case_table_filtered)} valid case.")

target_table = 'db2_case_table'

# Fetch the target table schema to determine the column names dynamically
try:
    query_table_schema = f"""
        SELECT column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_name = '{target_table}';
    """
    df_table_schema = pd.read_sql(query_table_schema, postgres_db.conn)
    target_columns = df_table_schema['column_name'].tolist()
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"Error fetching schema for table {target_table}: {e}")
    raise

# Convert epoch timestamps to datetime for `occurence_timestamp` and other timestamp columns
timestamp_columns = [
    'occurence_timestamp', 'reported_timestamp', 'created_timestamp', 'modified_timestamp', 
    'agency_extract_timestamp', 'city_extract_timestamp', 'pdf_extract_timestamp'
]

for col in timestamp_columns:
    if col in df_db1_case_table_filtered.columns:
        if df_db1_case_table_filtered[col].dtype in ['int64', 'float64']:
            df_db1_case_table_filtered[col] = pd.to_datetime(
                df_db1_case_table_filtered[col], unit='s', errors='coerce'
            )
        elif pd.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype(df_db1_case_table_filtered[col]):
            df_db1_case_table_filtered[col] = df_db1_case_table_filtered[col].dt.tz_localize(None)

# Ensure the correct columns are included in `df_for_insertion`
df_for_insertion = df_db1_case_table_filtered[
    [col for col in df_db1_case_table_filtered.columns if col in target_columns]
]

logging.info(df_for_insertion.dtypes)
logging.info(df_for_insertion[['occurence_timestamp']].head())

# Insert the filtered and dynamically mapped data into PostgreSQL
try:
    # Convert the DataFrame into a list of tuples
    data_to_insert = df_for_insertion.to_records(index=False).tolist()
    logging.info(data_to_insert[:5])

    # Generate the INSERT query dynamically based on the DataFrame columns
    columns = ', '.join(df_for_insertion.columns)
    placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(df_for_insertion.columns))
    insert_query = f"INSERT INTO {target_table} ({columns}) VALUES ({placeholders})"

    # Execute the batch insert
    with postgres_db.conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.executemany(insert_query, data_to_insert)
        postgres_db.conn.commit()
    
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"Error while inserting data into table {target_table}: {e}")
    raise

Additional information:
This is the print out of the check of column type from the dataframe
occurence_timestamp             datetime64[ns]
reported_timestamp              datetime64[ns]

This is the sample example of occurence_timestamp values
occurence_timestamp
0 2023-07-18 20:20:00
1 2023-09-21 17:00:00
2 2023-09-21 15:48:00
3 2023-09-21 21:30:00
4 2023-09-11 08:45:00


Try converting the datetime to string format
df['occurence_timestamp'] = df['occurence_timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Unfortunately I am unable to test as I dont have postgres in my local.
